# trailing characters error VIM

Tags: regex, vim

I have used this pattern successfully in the past, and now I'm getting the trailing characters error when using it for other documents:

```
%s#\[\#\#dname = \w\{2,6}\]#Variable #\1#g
```

I am trying to replace all instances of "[##dname = xxxxx]" with "Variable xxxxx" but the replacement string isn't working anymore. Any ideas? The capture string picks up just fine (when I use it in Find/Replace).

Thanks in advance!
SEAN

Answer (score 3):

You are not capturing the variable value and you have an extra `#`

```
%s#\[\#\#dname = \(\w\{2,6}\)\]#Variable \1#g
```

Comment: Also using `#` as substitute separator is only worsening things, when `#` is part of the search string; nothing wrong with the default `/` :).